# Application behind NGINX proxy cant send e-mails

Tags: nginx

In my current set up i have a web application which normally can send e-mails when not using a reverse proxy.

The application and the site are not running on HTTPS rather on HTTP.

Recently i  tried to use a reverse proxy to make the application run behind HTTPS and use CA certificates

Below is the nginx conf file

```
upstream app.domain.com 
        server 192.168.100.47:8080;
    
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name app.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/certs/cert1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/certs/cert1.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    keepalive_timeout 60;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect on;

        proxy_pass http://app.domain.gr/;
    }
}
```

Also note that nginx is running on a docker container , but i doubt that that is relevant

Thanks in advance

Comment: the final proxy_pass command is http://app.domain.com not app domain.gr FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginx reverse proxy is responsible for HTTP/HTTPS traffic to your application, but not for outgoing mail from your application.

Have you already debugged your application regarding mail sending?

For sending mail your application must be able to contact the corresponding mail server via SMTP, often port 25 or port 465 (TLS secured).

Comment: The application is hosted on a windows server , along with the web interface and all of its associated functions. For example we can create e-mail calls to a separate  mail server which handles the e-mails for the application. (an exchange server to be exact). all of this work over simple http, but when trying to put the application host server behind a proxy , the e-mail functionality of the application breaks. Maybe i should inlcude a some commands for the  e-mail server in the nginx configuration  but i am not certain that this would help

Comment: For me it is still very unclear what the structure of the interaction of your applications is. So unfortunately I can't guess where something might go wrong in the process.

Also, it is still unclear to me if your application actually sends an email (SMTP) or via API call the mail sending is done by another server or application.

Maybe you should create a small structure diagram or something similar, so that someone is able to identify your problem and provide you with a solution.